# HTTP Base Auth for a Swarm service behind Traefik reverse proxy

Tags: docker, http-basic-authentication, rabbitmq, docker-swarm, traefik

I'm running a Docker Swarm cluster with services behind Traefik2 with HTTPS Base Auth enabled in Traefik itself. Now i'd like to add RabbitMQ with its management interface and make the web management interface accessible through Traefiks port 443.

Unfortunately, I did neither find an option to disable the HTTP base auth of RabbitMQs management interface, nor found anything in Traefiks documentation to make Traefik authenticate to the service. And I am not really keen on adding my users to RabbitMQs web management plugin.

Does anyone maybe have a hint which service labels I could use to make Traefik perform HTTP base auth against RabbitMQs web management interface with its default user?

PS: Please excuse my bad english, I heavily lack of training...